# Selenium python check if the searched element appears within a period of time

Tags: python, selenium

Please help me.

I need to check if an element appears. The element may or may not appear. I want to check if the element appears in an x period of time, but, I still need to refresh the page during this entire period of time, the element does not appear without refreshing the page

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 9000)
element = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//b[contains(text(), '" + autor + "')]")))
```

This code is not what I need, besides what I need to check in x period of time, during this entire period I also need to refresh the page

Comment: Have you tried `presence_of_element_located` instead ?

Comment: It would work if the element appeared on the page, but the element on the page does not appear without refreshing the web page. I need the refresh the web page while it is waiting element

Comment: I'm a bit confused: can you expand on `'I don't feel like solving a problem'`? Also, you need to post a minimal reproducible example (including url of the page), and clearly state your end goal: what are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: sorry, problem with google translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, solution in my problem:

```
while True:
if autor in driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tbody/tr/td[2]/b").text:
    break
else:
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(15)
```

**autor** is variable who was receiving a text